# ASP.NET WebForm App_Theme caused compilation error

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a WebForm that references a Theme like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Test" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Test.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test"  Theme="TestTheme"%>
```

and the TestTheme only contains one Test.skin file with following content:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="button" />
```

If I execute the page, I always get a compilation error message like this:

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741701.
```

After looking closely through the generated html, I found this hidden message:

```
<!-- 
[HttpCompileException]: External component has thrown an exception.
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.ThemeDirectoryCompiler.GetThemeBuildResultType(String themeName)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ThemeDirectoryCompiler.GetThemeBuildResultType(HttpContext context, String themeName)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.InitializeThemes()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)...... and many more
```

However, if I remove the theme reference, everything works fine.

I guess there might be something wrong with compiling App_Theme files, but just had no idea how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. It looks like it happens on Win 8.1 or Win Server 2012 R2.
This is what I've done:

- Uninstalled Visual Studio 2015
- Uninstalled .Net framework 4.6
- Uninstalled following windows updates (KB3074232, KB3098000, KB3098785, KB3074553, KB3083185, KB3097992, KB3097997)
- Windows restart

After that I installed again updates in this order (KB3097992, KB3097997) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please restart and  delete the project files (.dll, .config, .pdb) from bin and rebuilt the project will solve the problem

Comment: I was running on IIS and had deleted all files under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files after system restart but still got the same problem.