# Web application doesn't run System.Web.HttpCompileException in Temporary ASP.NET Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I work with Visual Studio 2013 and have a web application which run on a local IIS (Version 8.5.9600.16384)

Since today I can't run the web application. If I open the website I got an Compile Error and our Logger write the following Error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Message><Exception><Message>Eine externe Komponente hat eine Ausnahme ausgel&#246;st.</Message><Type>System.Web.HttpCompileException</Type><StackTrace>   bei System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   bei System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   bei System.Web.Compilation.ThemeDirectoryCompiler.GetThemeBuildResultType(String themeName)
   bei System.Web.Compilation.ThemeDirectoryCompiler.GetThemeBuildResultType(HttpContext context, String themeName)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.InitializeThemes()
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   bei System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   bei ASP.login_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ebs.newtraffic.web\b5debfab\c81db55c\App_Web_boau4ge3.0.cs:Zeile 0.
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)</StackTrace></Exception></Message>
```

The other team members don't have any problems with the current Revision. A few days ago I installed Visual Studio 2015 and TFS for testing and I think this could be the problem.

I already:

- Restart the IIS
- Restart the PC
- Delete the File/Folders in Temporary ASP.NET Files
- Check the Security and give the IIS_IUSRS full control on the following folders

  - Temporary ASP.NET Files
  - C:\Windows\Temp
- Clean/Build the entire solution (VS2013 and VS2015)
- Repair .Net Framework 4.0 with "Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool

and it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar issue. Try the solution suggested here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514606/asp-net-webform-app-theme-caused-compilation-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514606/asp-net-webform-app-theme-caused-compilation-error)